# Event Max Participant Option Not Respected

Tags: civievent

the max particapent functionality works via the front-end but if someone is registered manually (say if they pay by cash at the shop) then the shop uses the back-end CiviCRM menu option "register event participent" under Events.

But the problem here is that if I have a priceset option to have a max participent of 1 (a time booking has a max of one person per slot) and that slot is taken, this will not be reflected in the back-end booking under "register event participent". And they will be able to choose any slot option regardless if that slot has already been taken. And thus creating double bookings.

Does anyone know if I am doing something wrong or is this an oversight?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, the max registrants is for the front-end, not the back-end. Often times when someone is manually registering someone in the back-end, they may need to override settings like the max registrations. So it doesn't take that into consideration. If you need it to be one only, then the person who is doing the registering should book it via the front-end like as if they were a customer (make sure you're not logged in when you do it). That will set them as pending since they didn't pay via your online method. Then you'd edit the record to reflect that they paid.